# Authorize Firestore server library in GKE

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using `google-cloud-firestore` python library in `GKE` But by default `firestore` lib is not authorize itself as like it automatically authorize in App Engine you don't need to provide any `service-account.json` file.

My `GKE` cluster and `firestore native mode` is in same project according to my think it should auto authorize on `GKE` as well but this is not correct.

I know I can authorize firestore library using `service-account.json` file. But I want to know is I'm doing something wrong or it does not auto authorize in GKE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you will need the `service-account.json` for Firestore to authorize the use with GKE, otherwise, it won't be possible to use it. I would recommend you take a look at this below article provides you more information and ideas on how to use GKE with Firestore.

- [Using Kubernetes, Google Firestore in GKE to orchestrate Scrapers using Scrapy Pt 1.](https://medium.com/faun/using-kubernetes-google-firestore-in-gke-to-orchestrate-scrapers-using-scrapy-pt-1-cdf7bb651341)

Let me know if the information helped you!